# Spring Security: Adding a "pseudo-login" to change user info

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-security

I've noticed that nearly every webapp with a "change user info" form requires a password to accept some fields. I'm trying to incorporate that functionality into a simple project, but I'm missing some key steps on the Spring Security side.

This was my attempt to build it *without* Spring Security verification.

Front end (JSP):

```
<form class="form mt-3" id="user-controls-form" method="POST" action="edituserinfo">
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-4"><label class="col-form-label" for="username">Username:</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-4"><label class="col-form-label" for="email">Email:</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-4"><label class="col-form-label" for="current-password">Current Password:</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="current-password" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-4"><label class="col-form-label" for="new-password">New Password:</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="new-password" placeholder="(if changing)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col offset-md-4"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-sm-2">Save</button></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Back end (Spring MVC):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edituserinfo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUserInfo(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication, Model model) {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    User user = dao.getUserByName(username);
    List<StaticPage> pages = spdao.getAllPages();
    model.addAttribute("pages", pages);

    User editedUser = new User();
    editedUser.setUserID(user.getUserID());
    editedUser.setAuthorities(user.getAuthorities());
    editedUser.setEnabled(user.isEnabled());

    if (request.getParameter("username").isBlank()) {
        editedUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    } else {
        editedUser.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
    }

    if (request.getParameter("new-password").isBlank()) {
        editedUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    } else {
        String clearPw = request.getParameter("new-password");
        String hashPw = encoder.encode(clearPw);
        editedUser.setPassword(hashPw);
    }

    if (request.getParameter("email").isBlank()) {
        editedUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    } else {
        editedUser.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    }

    String clearPw = request.getParameter("current-password");
    String hashPw = encoder.encode(clearPw);
    if (hashPw.equals(user.getPassword())) {
        dao.updateUser(editedUser);
    }

    return "redirect:usercontrols";
}
```

The problem is (obviously?) that the newly-hashcoded "current-password" value doesn't match the user's actual current password hashcode, even though the clear text values are the same. I know Spring Security's login feature takes care of this, but I've only ever used that for, well, logins. What can I do to create a "pseudo-login" functionality on this page, so that the user can't change their info without entering their current password?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing them yourself, consider using `PasswordEncoder#matches`. From the JavaDoc:

```java
/**
 * Verify the encoded password obtained from storage matches the submitted raw
 * password after it too is encoded. Returns true if the passwords match, false if
 * they do not. The stored password itself is never decoded.
 * @param rawPassword the raw password to encode and match
 * @param encodedPassword the encoded password from storage to compare with
 * @return true if the raw password, after encoding, matches the encoded password from
 * storage
 */
```

So, instead do:

```java
String clearPw = request.getParameter("current-password");
if (encoder.matches(clearPw, user.getPassword())) {
    dao.updateUser(editedUser);
}
```